# JQ: Count number of times string appears

Tags: arrays, bash, command-line, count, jq

```
map({Animal: .[].payload.animal})
|   map(select(.Animal))[][]
```

Using the following code, I get the following output of my very long JSON:

```
[
  [
    "Dog",
    "Cat"
  ]
]
[
  [
    "Dog",
    "Cat",
    "Bird"
  ]
]
```

From this output, how do I build/add to my JQ command to get the result 2 (the total of occurrences of dogs). I've played around (for hours!) with combinations of  add and select statements to try and get the desired output, but have not been able to. Would truly appreciate help on this!

---

As requested:

Sample input:

```
[{
    "Data": {
        "IsInUS": 1,
        "Pets": [
            ["Dog", "Cat", "Bird"]
        ],
        "Favorite Pet": "Dog"
    },
    "UniqueID": "1234"
},
{
    "Data": {
        "IsInUS": 1,
        "Pets": [
            ["Dog", "Cat", "Bird"]
        ]
        "Favorite Pet": "Cat"
    },
    "UniqueID": "234"
}]
```

Sample output: 2 (counting the number of dogs).

i am looking to count the occurrences of "Dog" only when it is in the "Pets" datafield/key

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: i have updated the question, thank you for the note and help!

Comment: I'm guessing your example is not valid JSON code.

Comment: hi cyus, i believe it is valid JSON (had an extra comma so i just added it)

Comment: Please fix the "sample input" so that it is valid JSON. You might like to use `jq empty` to validate, or jsonlint.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final trailing `[]` in your primary query results in a stream, which is not so good for counting using `length`.  For simplicity, you could go with:

```
map({Animal: .[].payload.animal})
|   map(select(.Animal))[]   # <--- JUST ONE []
| flatten
| map(select(. == "Dog"))
| length
```

### From scratch

You might like to consider simply counting the number of occurrences of "Dog" in your original JSON:

```
[.. | strings | select(. == "Dog")] | length
```

### Counting items in a stream

A more efficient way to count is by counting items in a stream:

```
def count(s): reduce s as $x (0; .+1);

count(.. | strings | select(. == "Dog"))
```

### Occurrences of "Dog" only when it is in .Pets

```
count(.. | objects | (.Pets // []) | flatten[] | select(.=="Dog"))
```

Comment: hi peak, this was actually very familiar with my best attempt at trying to get my ideal output, but is there a way to sum up the numbers to 2 at the end instead of getting
    1
    1

Comment: which [ ] are you referring to? the one around after Pets? If that is the case, how do I remove one set? As for the edit, the word Dog actually appears in other data fields, I trimmed them out to keep the example simple. I will update the sample input in my question to account for this.

Comment: The following has two trailing occurrences of `[]`: map({Animal: .[].payload.animal})
|   map(select(.Animal))[][]

Comment: got it. it definitely feels like bad practice to be using those 2, i just couldn't think of another way as i am inexperienced. barring that, considering the sample input and trying to achieve the sample output, would the count function not over-count due to the "Favorite Pet" field?

Comment: The count function is the best way to count, but you have to decide what you want to count.

Comment: i'd like to count the occurrences of "Dog" only when it is in the "Pets" datafield/key.